# Add background image to mat-dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-dialog

I am trying to add a background image to a mat-dialog but it does not show at all. I've even tried using a panelClass but no success.

```
.custom-panel .mat-dialog-container {
    background-image: url("../../../../assets/images/alerts/error-bg.png") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    .mat-dialog-title {
        font-family: $fnt-main;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably need `::ng-deep`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't see the image because you haven't specified width and height, try adding specific values, for example: `width: 5rem; height: 5rem`;

Comment: to the image, not the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add .custom-panel class and its containing styles in the root styles.scss file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a component that is what you show inside mat-dialog, then you should add this background style to your css/scss like this:

```
:host {
    background-image: url(<the-right-location-of-your-image>);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Read [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/) a detailed explanation about style isolation.

Comment: The path of the url **should be**:`url("assets/images/alerts/error-bg.png")`. Angular copy in "dist folder" your assets and is in this folder where create the index.html and put the .css. So the relative path is about this folder -it's equal the folder where you has your component-

Comment: @Eliseo thanks. I generalized the url because it's the principle that matters, not the specific image.